# Limit number of lines in ListView using jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile-listview

I was wondering how I could limit the number of lines in a jQueryMobile ListView.

I've prepared a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/enn3m/4/)** which looks basically like this (see description below):

[image]

What I would like to have is a limitation of the text length on three lines, which can be seen in the first row `#1`. Row `#2` shows the whole content (which is identically to `#1`), but its not limited to three lines. How could I limit the number of lines to three? Also I would like to add "..." at the end of a text, if it is longer than three lines.

Row `#3` shows the default of jQueryMobile (if I do not add the CSS style `white-space: normal;`, but that is limited to one line. Can I change that behavior?

**Note:** I build a web app / hybrid app using Phonegap/Cordova, means the solutions is expected to run on such browsers for iOS, Android and Windows Phone.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the three-lines stuff:

```
.limitedLines, .multipleLines {
    white-space: normal;
    line-height:1em;
    max-height:3em;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

The `text-overflow: ellipsis` should insert the `...` at the end of the line, but it is not working me in Chrome.

**Edit:** Of course, no Javascript required.

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enn3m/5/)

Comment: Thank you. The limitation works on Firefox, but the `...` are not inserted at the end. Any idea why it's not working? I will test it on some mobile devices by tomorrow, since it has to run on iOS, Android and Windows Phone devices (using Phonegap with jQuery Mobile). Any idea how to make it run on all browsers? I thought jQuery Mobile should have something compatible for all browsers.